# Getting to the Recent Activity page from the menu

Tags: support, recent-activity

When I login to SO, I get a recent activity link like this:
`http://serverfault.com/users/recent/21955/2009-11-01/2009-11-02?tab=responses`

How do I get to this page from the menu, and not using the link I get when I logged in.
(It is a better view than the one I have in the profile).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get to that page at any time - just click the envelope http://sstatic.net/mso/img/replies-off.png at the top of the page and click the "responses" tab.